# Aligning lines in CSS

Tags: css, alignment

Help a CSS newbie out here. What I'm trying to do is very simple.

[image]

As I said in the image, I want the text to be in the same line. I tried everything i could think of.

Here is the index.php:
http://pastebin.com/9LVVFgUZ
Here is the style.css:
http://pastebin.com/v8Eius2A

Thanks.

Comment: it would be better if gave us the generated html

Comment: I'd be quite appreciative of a text that doesn't involve so much profanity, personally. :/

Comment: I actually lold at the phrase. But yes you shouldn't be posting such thing here. And yes please post the generated html.

Comment: Here is the generated HTML - http://lajkuvaj.tk//

Comment: And BTW, i'm sorry for the profanity. It was just an example :P

Comment: No, that's the php that produces the page. What's the actual HTML mark-up **as seen in the browser** ('view source')?

Comment: That was the actual site, thus the HTML optput. But here is the HTML anyway. **http://pastebin.com/GG2XS9z8**

Comment: Does adding to `.box_con a`: `float: left` and `width: 470px` get you close to what you want?

Comment: @thirtydot That pretty much solves my problem. Thanks!

Comment: @Крсте Поткоњак: Take a look at @Sotiris answer. It's pretty much identical to my comment, so you can give him the accept. I don't mind.

Comment: @thirtydot sorry but your comment was in the hidden, and I didn't see it, but you gave the answer first :) I deleted mine.

Comment: Thank you both anyway. I can't vote in the comments but pretend I did ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Original code:

```
.box_con a {
    color: #111111;
    font-family: Georgia,"Times New Roman",Times,serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding-left: 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 470px;
}
```

Remove the float, make the a element block-level and add a left margin like so:

```
.box_con a {
    color: #111111;
    display: block;
    font-family: Georgia,"Times New Roman",Times,serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-left: 150px;
    padding-left: 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 470px;
}
```

Result:

[image: result]

Answer (score 2):

Adding to `.box_con a` these rules: `float: left` and `width: 470px` seems to get what you asked for in your image.